# Automating a Password Reset flow with Testcafe

Tags: automation, ui-automation, testcafe

My goal is to somehow send the email and click the link to reset the password, access that link and write a new password. Don't really know if this is possible or could only be mocked.

I would also like to catch the content of the email and check it. Is there a way within TestCafe to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use TestCafe to fill out and submit the password recovery form that will initiate a request to your backend. After that, you can use either of the following solutions:

1. Intercept this request to the backend using TestCafe features for [Intercepting HTTP Requests](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/advanced-guides/intercept-http-requests.html). Then, make sure that the "an email with a retrieval link was sent" message was shown, navigate to the known in advance retrieval link and log in with a new password.
2. Make this request to the backend actually initiate sending an email. Then, in your test, connect to an email service (using some of the Node.js email clients), receive the email, and navigate TestCafe to the link.

The first approach seems to be more robust because it doesn't rely on any third-party services.

Comment: Seems that (1) won't be helpful because there is no http request to catch.
For (2), I've found node-imap, but couldn't make it work yet. I'm trying to read emails from a gmail account but i get unauthorized.

Comment: Hope you can resolve this. Also, if you decide to follow the second approach and you struggle with using Node.js email clients directly, you can try some 3rd-party services (like [Mailosaur](https://mailosaur.com/docs/languages/nodejs/)) that provide an API to fetch emails just for these purposes.

Comment: Managed to get emails, now i need something to parse out the bodies. I need to get the links embedded there.